# How to get the CPU/memory profiling graph of Go tests as an image

Tags: unit-testing, go, visual-studio-code, profiling, graphviz

I'm using VS Code to run Go tests along with CPU/memory profiling:

[image: Screenshot]

## Question

How can I download/save the graph as an image?

## Tried

I downloaded the result as a `*.gz` file:

[image: Screenshot: *.gz file]

Then I used these commands to convert the `*.gz` file to an image. But I'm getting errors:

```bash
dot -Tpng -Gdpi=1024 profile.pb.gz > profile.pb.gz.png
Error: profile.pb.gz: syntax error in line 1 near '▼'
```

Also:

```bash
dot -Tpng profile.pb.gz  -o profile.pb.gz.png
Error: profile.pb.gz: syntax error in line 1 near '▼'
```

Comment: dot canot gunzip files on the fly, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Volker I thought the `*.gz` stands for GraphViz, not GZip. I thought it's a GraphViz specific file type.

Comment: What does file tell you? What do you see if you look at the file?

Comment: @Volker Well, the `file` command indicates it's a `gzip` compressed file by this message: `profile.pb.gz: gzip compressed data, original size modulo 2^32 3339`

Comment: @Volker I extracted the `gzip` file. It contains a binary file with a `*.pb` extension.

Comment: @Volker But the main question is how to export the profiler graph as an image.

Comment: @Volker This repository has some info about the `*.pb` file format: https://github.com/google/pprof

Comment: I really do not understand your question. This is profile data and you work with that data via `go tool pprof`. Running `go tool pprof -h` mentions some 20 output formats from text to dot/graphviz, pdf and png. Just use that, no need to go fancy here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

profile.pb.gz contains (compressed) profiling data. It has nothing to do with Graphviz.

Go includes the pprof tool to extract information from this data in various formats, including PNG, GIF, or SVG encoded images:

```
$ go tool pprof -png profile.pb.gz > foo.png
$ file foo.png
foo.png: PNG image data, 1164 x 1344, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Note that there is no need to gunzip the file.

See `go tool pprof -h` for more options.

Comment: I tested, your suggestion works :)

Comment: The question is, why does VS Code not let us export a graph as an image via its UI? Where can I request this feature? Which GitHub repository?

Answer (score -3):

These steps might work, but not been tried yet:

1. Download a `*.gz` file by VS Code UI.
2. Extract the `*.gz` file and get a `*.pb` file.
3. Work with the `*.pb` file by this repository: https://github.com/google/pprof